# How to create tags of xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have array like this

```
{
    AID : "111",
    BID: "222"
}

{
    AID : "311",
    BID: "422"
}

{
    AID : "511",
    BID: "622"
}

{
    AID : "711",
    BID: "822"
}
```

Which I need to place in xml like this

```
<ROOT>
    <D>AID = 111 BID: "222" />
    <D>AID = 211 BID: "322" />
    <D>AID = 411 BID: "522" />
    <D>AID = 611 BID: "722" />
</ROOT>
```

Now I am not able to create any xml tag from javascript therefore I am using this technique.

```
var DTag = [];

for loop {
                var AIDVal = this.AID;
                var BIDVal = this.BID;
                var dTag = "<D AID="+AIDVal+" BID="+BIDVal+"</I>";
}

DTag.push(dTag);
```

By doing this  I am getting something like array of

```
[   "<D>AID = 111 BID: "222" ></D>",
    "<D>AID = 211 BID: "322" ></D>",
    "<D>AID = 411 BID: "522" ></D>",
    "<D>AID = 611 BID: "722" ></D>"]
```

and then I am adding in root tag like
`var xmlData = "<R>"+ DTag.join() +"</R>"`

But I am not getting xmlDaat in properly. getting some html body. How to create tag of xml in javascript.
var 
`var xmlContent = ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlData , "text/xml");` In this line I am getting error.

Comment: `var xmlData = "<R>"+ DTag.join("") +"</R>"`

Comment: *"Which I need to place in xml like this"* You need `</D>`, not `/>`, in that. And no, it doesn't make sense to ask people to ignore syntax errors (in the XML or the JavaScript). In this case, we can probably guess what it's meant to be, but really, it's down to you to take the time to provide accurate information.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My apology, I updated my question

Comment: @David: But didn't fix the syntax errors; you just removed the bit asking us to ignore them.

Comment: @epascarello I update my question and pointed Where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Well your join() is wrong above

Comment: @epascarello Thanks sir. It is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your xml by joining the array and wrap with the ROOT tag:

```js
var arr = [
{
    AID : "111",
    BID: "222"
},
{
    AID : "311",
    BID: "422"
},
{
    AID : "511",
    BID: "622"
},
{
    AID : "711",
    BID: "822"
}];

var arrRes = arr.map(function(obj){
  return "<D> AID = " + obj.AID + " BID: " + obj.BID + "</D>"
});


console.log("<ROOT>" + arrRes.join("") + "</ROOT>")
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon. Add an explaination